# Quais IPs e Portas eu preciso ter liberado para trabalhar com Composer e Git?

Tags: php, git, composer, redes

A empresa na qual trabalho vai implementar uma rede corporativa na qual, existem vários bloqueios de IPs e Portas.

Preciso levantar todos os IPs e portas que preciso usar para solicitar a liberação dos mesmos.

Trabalho com PHP, Git e Composer e não tenho ideia de quais IPs preciso solicitar liberação (Perincipalmente no caso do Composer, onde existem várias dependências e algumas, tem outras dependências).

Alguém pode me ajudar a identificar isso?

OBS: Uso Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sobre o `Git` você pode conferir neste link do `Github` que ele vai te informar sobre

[About GitHub's IP addresses](https://help.github.com/articles/about-github-s-ip-addresses/)

O `Composer` creio utilizar por padrão as portas **80, 443**